# ClassNotFoundException with m2e-wtp in Eclips on republish

Tags: spring, m2e-wtp

We're using Eclipse 4.5.1 with m2e 1.6.2 and m2e-wtp 1.2.1 for deploying a multi-module webapp to a Tomcat 8 server.

We have enabled "Serve modules without publishing" and "Modules auto reload by default" in the server's configuration in Eclipse.

When we start the server the webapp comes up normally, but after the first code change & recompile in a dependent module the server tries to republish and throws `ClassNotFoundException` for every class we defined as listener in our *web.xml*, in special these are

```
org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.eclipse.rap.rwt.engine.RWTServletContextListener
```

and some custom listeners, but all of them are in the classpath, because the first start or restart of the server via "play button" in Eclipse works fine.

Has anyone any hint where to look further?

Comment: I frequently face ClassNotFoundExceptions after deploying (publishing) my project on eclipse too. Same Eclipse and m2e/m2e-wtp versions here. It appear to be a somewhat random problem for me (at least I didn't realized how it works...).
When that happens to me, I try the full build cycle again: Maven update, Maven install (with m2e context menu) and Full Publish projects on server. Did you tried it?